How can I convert Stream to D3DImage using SharpDX 4.2.0?
I want to display byte[] which is jpg on D3DImage in WPF app using SharpDX 4.2.0.
As I know, I should do below steps to get to finish this.
EDIT :
I made two D3D11.Texture2D, one for write pixel and one for share for d3d9 and it's compiled but screen shows nothing. I hope someone guide me why it's not showing image.
step 1. Stream to SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D
step 2. create SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D d3dTexture_Draw and write pixel on it.
step 3. create SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D _finalTexture  to share to Direct3D9.Texture
step 4. d11dContext.CopyResource(d3dTexture_Draw, _finalTexture);
step 5. share _finalTexture to Direct3D9.Texture
step 6.  D3DImage.SetBackBuffer Direct3D9.Texture's surface
I hope to get any help for this.
EDIT :
@Simon Mourier : Your answer works greatly!
private void LoadBmpToTexture(string filePath)
{
    // Load the JPEG into a Bitmap
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(filePath))
    {
        SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None | DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_11_0);
        SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext d11dContext = device.ImmediateContext;

        byte[] byteArray = ConvertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);                
        using (var imagingFactory = new SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2())
        {
            var decoder = new SharpDX.WIC.BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, memoryStream, DecodeOptions.CacheOnLoad);
            var frame = decoder.GetFrame(0);
            var formatConverter = new FormatConverter(imagingFactory);
            formatConverter.Initialize(frame, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA);

            var width = formatConverter.Size.Width;
            var height = formatConverter.Size.Height;

            var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
            {
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                MipLevels = 1,
                ArraySize = 1,
                Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write,

            };

            var d3dTexture_Draw = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);

            // Copy data to Texture2D
            var dataBox = d11dContext.MapSubresource(d3dTexture_Draw, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);
            using (var wicStream = new DataStream(dataBox.DataPointer, width * height * 4, true, true))
            {
                formatConverter.CopyPixels(width * 4, wicStream);
            }
            d11dContext.UnmapSubresource(d3dTexture_Draw, 0);


            var final_descriptor = new Texture2DDescription()
            {
                Width = (int)img.Width,
                Height = (int)img.Height,
                ArraySize = 1,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                MipLevels = 1,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0)
            };

            Texture2D _finalTexture = new Texture2D(device, final_descriptor);

            d11dContext.CopyResource(d3dTexture_Draw, _finalTexture);

            SharpDX.Direct3D9.Direct3DEx d9context = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Direct3DEx();
            SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device d9device = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device(d9context,
                                                                0,
                                                                DeviceType.Hardware,
                                                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                                                CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing,
                                                                new SharpDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters()
                                                                {
                                                                    Windowed = true,
                                                                    SwapEffect = SharpDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard,
                                                                    DeviceWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle,
                                                                    PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate,
                                                                });

            IntPtr renderTextureHandle = _finalTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Resource>().SharedHandle;

            SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture d9texture = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture(d9device,
                                                                   _finalTexture.Description.Width,
                                                                   _finalTexture.Description.Height,
                                                                   1,
                                                                   SharpDX.Direct3D9.Usage.RenderTarget,
                                                                   SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8,
                                                                   Pool.Default,
                                                                   ref renderTextureHandle);
            
            d3dImage = new D3DImage();
            d3dImage.Lock();
            
            d3dImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, d9texture.GetSurfaceLevel(0).NativePointer, true);

            //Image d3dImage : Width=720, Height=370
            d3dImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 720, 370));
            d3dImage.Unlock();
            img.Source= d3dImage;
        }
    }
}


Why does your code contains D3D11 and DXGI code while D3DImage expects a D3D9 surface pointer? You can get a surface from d3d9Device's CreateOffscreenPlainSurface call LockRect on it write the bitmap bits, call UnlockRect, and pass that to SetBackBuffer. But it also depends on the input stream, what is it exactly?

@SimonMourier I'm new at DirectX and SharpDX. So I followed pieces of info from google and gpt. Thx for your guidance and I'll try it.

You should post a reproducing project somewhere

It's here -> https://github.com/NuclearPark/D3DImage-with-SharpDX

Here's a solution that only uses WIC and DirectX 9:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly D3DImage _d3dImage = new();

    // you can keep the device if you want to use it
    private readonly SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device _device;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => LoadJpegToTexture(@"sample.bmp");

        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
        using var context = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D();
        _device = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device(context,
            0,
            SharpDX.Direct3D9.DeviceType.Hardware,
            hwnd,
            SharpDX.Direct3D9.CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing,
            new SharpDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters()
            {
                Windowed = true,
                SwapEffect = SharpDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard,
                DeviceWindowHandle = hwnd,
                PresentationInterval = SharpDX.Direct3D9.PresentInterval.Immediate,
            });

        img.Source = _d3dImage;
    }

    private void LoadJpegToTexture(string filePath)
    {
        using var imagingFactory = new SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2();
        using var decoder = new SharpDX.WIC.BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, filePath, SharpDX.WIC.DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
        using var frame = decoder.GetFrame(0);

        // depending on the image's pixel format, you must convert the frame
        // to match DirectX 9 RGBA surface format
        using var converter = new SharpDX.WIC.FormatConverter(imagingFactory);
        converter.Initialize(frame, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppBGRA);

        // create a render target surface
        using var surface = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Surface.CreateRenderTarget(_device,
            frame.Size.Width,
            frame.Size.Height,
            SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8,
            SharpDX.Direct3D9.MultisampleType.None,
            0,
            true
            );

        // copy pixels from WIC to surface
        var rc = surface.LockRectangle(SharpDX.Direct3D9.LockFlags.None);
        converter.CopyPixels(rc.Pitch, rc.DataPointer, frame.Size.Height * rc.Pitch);
        surface.UnlockRectangle();

        _d3dImage.Lock();
        _d3dImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, surface.NativePointer, true);
        _d3dImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height));
        _d3dImage.Unlock();
    }
}


This is amazing you saved my 100++hours. Deeply appreciated. Bless you. As soon as I get 15 reputation I'll vote your answer up.

@Clemens : Good point Clemens.
